# Restore in-app purchases with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

It's very strange, but I couldn't find it in official Parse documentation. According to Parse, it's very easy to make nonconsumable purchase:

```
// First, register a handler for the product
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"Pro" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
    // Write business logic that should run once this product is purchased.
    isPro = YES;
}];

// … Later, when the user is purchasing the product:
[PFPurchase buyProduct:@"Pro" block:^(NSError *error) { … }];
```

But what if I have the following case: an app was launched and then I have to check if user had bought item X. With Parse we may restore all the purchases using this:

```
[PFPurchase restore];
```

But how I can know, if item X was bought earlier or not? Answer must be very easy, but I simply can't find it anywhere in google(

Comment: Is your question how to process restoration or how to persist that the "pro" product was purchased at all?

Comment: @Paulw11 How to process all purchases we know: [PFPurchase restore]. I meant second part: "how to persist that the "pro" product was purchased at all".

Comment: That functionality isn't provided by the Parse framework.  One common approach is to store data in the keychain